# When are the default values to data members assigned?

Tags: system-verilog

In my company we are moving to a new flow and in the process we accidently meesed up with VCS settings, and even after reverting back to the same VCS version we are unable to fix it.
Below is the psudocode code of the issue.

[EdaPlayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/cdiz) Also copied  here

Now I intent to understand the execution order of below two lines. Depending on this order the 'socket_id' displayed inside program block could be 25/-25.

1. int socket_id  = -25;
2. socket_id = 25;

*Query1: How to configure VCS, such that  the socket_id is set to 25?*
We are using VCS N-2017.12-SP2-6 , which gives different result in two different DB. In one DB(old) we get socket_id set to '25', while in the other DB(new)  we are getting it as '-25'. I raised this issue at solvenet where I was told that '-25' is the right value. Since this is a legacy code, it would have worked correctly, if socket_id is set to 25. But I am not sure how to make VCS do this.

*Query2: Why this code output is not consisstent across different simulators?*
Also when I tried this code at EdaPlayground, I was surprised to find that the execution of this code was not consistent across different simulators. It looked like Mentor/Aldec is not doing it correctly,  while VCS/Cadence output seems correct. For convinience I have copied the outputs below.

Pseudo code:

```
class Base;
   
  function new();
    $display("Base:new");
    set_derived();
  endfunction
  
  virtual function void set_derived ();
    $display("Base: set_drived");
  endfunction 
  
endclass

class Child extends Base;
  
 int socket_id  = -25;
 int socket_id1; 
  
  function new();
    super.new();
    $display("Child:new");
    $display("Child: new: socket_id = %d", socket_id);
  endfunction
  
  virtual function void set_derived ();
    $display("Child: set_drived");
    $display("Child: set_derived: socket_id = %d", socket_id);
    socket_id = 25;
    socket_id1 = 25;
    $display("Child: set_derived: socket_id = %d", socket_id);
    //super.set_drived();
  endfunction  
endclass

program test;
  
  Child c;
  
  initial begin
    c = new();
    $display("Program: socket_id = %d socket_id1 = %d", c.socket_id, c.socket_id1);
  end
  
  
endprogram
```

Results from different simulators.

1. Questa 2021.3

```
# Base:new
# Base: set_drived
# Child:new
# Child: new: socket_id =         -25
# Program: socket_id =         -25 socket_id1 =           0
```

2. VCS 2020.03

```
Base:new
Child: set_drived
Child: set_derived: socket_id =           0
Child: set_derived: socket_id =          25
Child:new
Child: new: socket_id =         -25
Program: socket_id =         -25 socket_id1 =          25
```

3. Cadence 20.09

```
Base:new
Child: set_drived
Child: set_derived: socket_id =           0
Child: set_derived: socket_id =          25
Child:new
Child: new: socket_id =         -25
Program: socket_id =         -25 socket_id1 =          25
```

4. Aldec

```
# KERNEL: Base:new
# KERNEL: Base: set_drived
# KERNEL: Child:new
# KERNEL: Child: new: socket_id =         -25
# KERNEL: Program: socket_id =         -25 socket_id1 =           0
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like questa and aldec do not call virtual methods from constructors, following c++ paradigm, however, the SV standard has at least this quot (8.17):

> NOTE 2—When calling a virtual method from a constructor new(), the constructor calls the method as described in
> 8.20. However, users must be aware of the class property initialization sequence as described in 8.7, as properties the
> method refers to may not have been initialized, depending on where in the chain of constructors the method was called
> from.

So, the questa and aldec do not follow the standard.

8.7 describes the order of initialization:

> If a class does not provide an explicit user-defined new method, an implicit new method shall be provided
> automatically. The new method of a derived class shall first call its base class constructor [super.new() as
> described in 8.15]. After the base class constructor call (if any) has completed, each property defined in the
> class shall be initialized to its explicit default value or its uninitialized value if no default is provided. After
> the properties are initialized, the remaining code in a user-defined constructor shall be evaluated. The default
> constructor has no additional effect after the property initialization. The value of a property prior to its
> initialization shall be undefined.

So, the order is the following:

1. Child::new -> super.new()
2. Base::new -> Child::set_derived, -> socket_id = 25
3. Child::socket_id-> -25 (class property initialization)
4. Child::new, the rest of the code.

As a result, it looks like vcs and cadence behave according to the standard, questa and aldec are not.

BTW, in object-oriented languages calling virtual functions from a constructor is considered to be dangerous for the reason of confusion in initialization orders.

Answer (score 2):

This was a recent [clarification](https://accellera.mantishub.io/view.php?id=2488) in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) from the 2012 version. Questa has a switch to get the new behavior (`-svext=+vmctor`), but using virtual methods in constructors is considered a bad programming practice most of the time anyways.

You should notice that `socket_id` still has the value 0 when most people expect it to be initialized with -25. That's because variable initializations happen as part of execution of the class constructor, but the extended class constructor has not executed yet at the point where the base constructor calls the virtual method.